# sql to select first n unique lines on sorted result

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have query resulting me 1 column of strings, result example:

```
NAME:
-----
SOF
OTP
OTP
OTP
SOF
VIL
OTP
SOF
GGG
```

I want to be able to get SOF, OTP, VIL - the first 3 unique top,
I tried using DISTINCT and GROUP BY, but it is not working, the sorting is damaged..

The query building this result is :

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.adst 
FROM   (SELECT a.date              adate, 
               b.date              bdate, 
               a.price + b.price   total, 
               ( b.date - a.date ) days, 
               a.dst               adst 
        FROM   flights a 
               JOIN flights b 
                 ON a.dst = b.dst 
        ORDER  BY total) d
```

I have "flights" table with details, and I need to get the 3 (=n) cheapest destinations.

Thanks

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Edit your question with your query that generates this result.

Comment: can you also explain what you mean by "first 3 unique top"? Why would the query return `VIL` but not `GGG` (both have 1 occurrence)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a way to do it.

I am selecting the DST and the PRICE, grouping by DST with MIN function on Price and limiting 3.

do I have better way to do it?

```
SELECT d.adst , min(d.total) mttl
FROM   (SELECT a.date              adate, 
               b.date              bdate, 
               a.price + b.price   total, 
               ( b.date - a.date ) days, 
               a.dst               adst 
    FROM   flights a 
           JOIN flights b 
             ON a.dst = b.dst 
    ORDER  BY total) d 
group by adst order by mttl;
```

Answer (score 3):

This can easily be done using window functions:

```
select *
from (
       SELECT a.date as adate, 
              b.date as bdate, 
              a.price + b.price as total, 
              dense_rank() over (order by a.price + b.price) as rnk,
              b.date - a.date as days, 
              a.dst  as adst 
        FROM  flights a 
          JOIN flights b ON a.dst = b.dst 
) t
where rnk <= 3
order by rnk;
```

More details on window functions can be found in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   name
from 
   testname 
where 
   name in (
   select distinct(name) from testname) 
group by name order by min(ctid) limit 3
```

<kbd>[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4d3bb/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak your query to return the correct result, by adding `where days > 0` and `limit 3` in the outer query like this:

```
select *
from 
(
   select 
     a.date adate, 
     b.date bdate, 
     (a.price + b.price) total, 
     (b.date - a.date) days , 
     a.dst adst
   from flights a 
   join flights b on a.dst = b.dst 
   order by total
) d
where days > 0
limit 3;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9a0ae/11)

**This assuming that the second entry is the return flight with `date` greater than the first entry. So that you got positive days difference.**

---

**Note that,** your query without `days > 0` will give you a cross join between the table and it self, for each flight you will get 4 rows, two with it self with days = 0 and other row with negative days so I used `days > 0` to get the correct row.

I recommend that you add a new column, an Id `Flight_Id` as a primary key, and another foreign key something like `From_Flight_Id`. So the primary flight would have a `null` `From_Flight_Id`, and the returning flight will have a `From_Flight_Id` equal to the `flight_id` of the primary filght, this way you can join them properly instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (column_name) FROM table_name order by name LIMIT 3;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`EnteredOn`) FROM `rm_pr_patients` Group By `EnteredOn`
```

Comment: sorry forget to add your attributes

Comment: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function. And using `\`` for identifiers is invalid sql. Plus the `distinct` is useless if you also do a `goup by` on the column. And there is no `rm_pr_patients` table in the question.